# Validating jquery rating stars

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Hi im trying to validate some jquery stars with jquery validate. i have found a couple of answers here about this , but tried both with no luck.

Here is the HTML in view source cause im on rails

But its not working, How can i validate the rating stars, to make them mandatory required, XD! thanks..i have been looking into this for days, pls help-

And as i said i have tried the answers in other questions, but they are not working for me

```
<div id="pasescortos"> 
    <label for="attribute">Short passes</label>
<span class="star-rating-control">
<div class="rating-cancel"><a title="Cancel Rating"></a></div>
<div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="player_short_passes_1">

<a title="1">1</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="player_short_passes_2">

<a title="2">2</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="player_short_passes_3">

<a title="3">3</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="player_short_passes_4">

<a title="4">4</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star star-rating-applied star-rating-live" id="player_short_passes_5">

<a title="5">5</a></div></span>

<input class="star star-rating-applied" id="player_short_passes_1" name="player[short_passes]" type="radio" value="1" style="display: none;">

<input class="star star-rating-applied" id="player_short_passes_2" name="player[short_passes]" type="radio" value="2" style="display: none;">

<input class="star star-rating-applied" id="player_short_passes_3" name="player[short_passes]" type="radio" value="3" style="display: none;">

<input class="star star-rating-applied" id="player_short_passes_4" name="player[short_passes]" type="radio" value="4" style="display: none;">

<input class="star star-rating-applied" id="player_short_passes_5" name="player[short_passes]" type="radio" value="5" style="display: none;">

  </div>
```

Here is JS.

```
$().ready(function() {

  // validate signup form on keyup and submit
$(".edit_player").validate({
ignore:'', // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div'});




$("#player_position").rules("add", { required: true,  messages: { required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>"}});

$("#player_short_passes_1").rules("add", { required: true,  messages: { required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>"}});


$("#player_dominant_leg").rules("add", { required: true,  messages: { required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>"}});

});





jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "<%= t('generales.camporequerido') %>",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Ingresa un correo electrónico válido.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
```

EDIT1:

I have notice in the HTML viewing source that my form has this novalidate=""

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/player_steps/skills?locale=en" class="edit_player" id="edit_player_17" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

The strange thing is i dont have a novalidate tag in Rails views, that is been generated in jquery.validate.js right?

this is how my form in rails look.

```
<%= form_for @player, :url => wizard_path do |f| %>
```

In jquery.rating.js about the doble id problem i found this.. how can i fix it?

```
// insert rating star
            var star = $('<div class="star-rating rater-'+ control.serial +'"><a title="' + (this.title || this.value) + '">' + this.value + '</a></div>');
            rater.append(star);

            // inherit attributes from input element
            if(this.id) star.attr('id', this.id);
            if(this.className) star.addClass(this.className);
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: If im trying to validate ,and i cant, anyway.. i would Edit question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you've got a couple minor mistakes.

First, you have two things with the same ID - one for each star and one for each radio.  You can only have one unique ID per element.  What happens when you call `$("#player_short_passes_1")` in this situation then, becomes undefined (most likely is that you get the first created element with that ID).  A better way to set these rules would be by just adding a `rules` option to your validate call:

```
$(".edit_player").validate({
    ignore:'', // initialize the plugin
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
      'player[short_passes]': {
        required:true
      }
   }
});
```

Remember that rules are defined by the **name** of the input, not by ID.  Note that the `player[short_passes]` key has to be quoted in the rules object, otherwise Javascript will throw an error.

One other thing is just to make sure that `.edit_player` is in fact a form.  jQuery Validate only works on forms, not something like a div.

Working example (ish - I didn't get the star plugin, so you just have to click on one of the numbers):  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/RghSK/

Comment: Ok just want to point this out,, that double ID is generated by my rating js file, cause in the RAils vies, i just generate radio buttons .. those divs are not in html, they appear once you "run" the site.. how can i change that id? im lost there

Comment: Honestly, you don't need to fix it - just reference the inputs as I suggested, by name.  You'll see in my example that I left the double IDs.  Whoever wrote that plugin should probably be notified :)

Comment: Ok i was trying to fix the ID issue to test this, i will test even with the double id thanks